# Regex to replace html whitespace and leading whitespace in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have tried to use the following regex expression to remove html whitespace and leading whitespace

```
Find:   \s*([<>])\s*

Replace: $1
```

But each time that I do this I end up with 186 occurrences of $1 literaly in my document. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Here is an example of what I am talking about

This

```
<fieldset id="prod_desc">
<p>Original AA </p>
<b>Features:</b> 
<ul>
  <li>2 pole rectangular dome tent with 13.4 sq ft of vestibule storage </li>
  <li>Durable, shockcorded, self-supporting fiberglass frame and ring and pin/pole pocket assembly </li>
  <li>2 side opening door panels are constructed entirely of no see-um mesh to maximize air flow inside </li>
  <li>Poke-out vent in side wall allows the option of additional ventilation when needed </li>
  <li>2 interior storage pockets keep essential items handy Specifications: </li>
  <li>Season: 3 </li>
  <li>Sleeps: 2 </li>
  <li>Doors: 2 </li>
  <li>Windows: 2 </li>
  <li>Weight: 5 lbs 12 oz </li>
  <li>Area: 36.5 Sq. Ft. </li>
  <li>Center Height: 3' 7.5&quot;</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

should become:

```
<fieldset id="prod_desc"><p>Original AA</p><b>Features:</b><ul><li>2 pole rectangular dome tent with 13.4 sq ft of vestibule storage</li><li>Durable, shockcorded, self-supporting fiberglass frame and ring and pin/pole pocket assembly</li><li>2 side opening door panels are constructed entirely of no see-um mesh to maximize air flow inside</li><li>Poke-out vent in side wall allows the option of additional ventilation when needed</li><li>2 interior storage pockets keep essential items handy Specifications:</li><li>Season: 3</li><li>Sleeps: 2</li><li>Doors: 2</li><li>Windows: 2</li><li>Weight: 5 lbs 12 oz</li><li>Area: 36.5 Sq. Ft.</li><li>Center Height: 3' 7.5&quot;</li></ul></fieldset>
```

Comment: try to replace with `\1`

Comment: I'd look at a plug-in, perhaps HTML Tidy with appropriate settings. Parsing HTML with regular expressions leads to pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't support `$1` for backreferences before version 6.0 when it introduced PCRE support for find-and-replace. For older versions, use `\1` for backreferences.

You should be finding `\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*`. As of Notepad++ version 6.0, released in March 2012, this alone should work for you. I tried your original regex and it works as well, much to my surprise.

Previous versions cannot do multi-line regex replacements. To strip newlines, perform the regex replacement first, then do an extended find (UNIX line endings):

```
\n
```

For Windows line endings:

```
\r\n
```

Replace either case with nothing.

Comment: @capnhud: It shouldn't replace with literal `\1` at least; see my edit.

Comment: when I say it did not do the trick, I was referring to no it do not replace with a literal $1, but instead just removed the leading whitespace in front of the tags on each line. So instead of ending of with just one line with all the html I still have 75 lines.

Comment: And that did the trick. Thanks for informing a little about notepad++

Comment: @capnhud: No problem, I've been a longtime user myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression `\s+\<(.*)\>\s+`  and replace with $1  (or \1 in Notepad++)

Or you could use this approach:

- first, match `\s+\<` and replace with `<`
- second, match  `\>\s+` and replace with `>`

Comment: this expression is still accomplishing the same thing as \s*([<>])\s* they are not removing the lines.

Comment: Sounds like Notepad++ has some funny behavior on regex searches, perhaps only searching line-by-line.  `\s+` should work.  You could always just follow it up with a search for `\n`, replace with nothing.

Comment: BoltClock just imformed me that notepad++ does not do multi-line regex replacements.